# Is it possible to add 2 lines in one row in UITableView (Swift)

Tags: uitableview, swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return titleList.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)->UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = ("\(titleList[indexPath.row]) - \(timeDayList[indexPath.row]):\(timeHourList[indexPath.row]):\(timeMinuteList[indexPath.row]):\(timeSecondList[indexPath.row])")
    return cell
}
```

I'd like to put the day, hour, minute, second into a new line. Is it possible or should I create another row for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a custom `UITableViewCell` and

1. Either add labels to it and stack them one under the other
2. Or have a `UITextView` and show them each in a new line

I would personally go with the first option.